# tufte-book does not produce ToC for a title with a line break with latex

Tags: latex, tufte

In a document, I have a title with a line break (written as `\\`). With `documentclass` `book` it produces a table of content as expected, but with `tufte-book` fails. I use

```
LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)  (format=lualatex 2023.7.3)  11 SEP 2023 14:37
```

and have tried to use `\protect` as recommended in some similar cases.

What must be changed to make it work with tufte-book?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
% {tufte-book} fails 
% {book} works 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}   
 
\begin{document}
 
\tableofcontents
 
\chapter{ix-hl1 Chapter Title} 

Introductory text for chapter.

     
\section{03title section title first line   \\ second line of title}
section text
 
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The errors seem to be in the `toc` file, but none is produced:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing $ inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Undefined control sequence. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
LaTeX hooks Error: Illegal mode change in hook 'para/begin'. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
You can't use `\lastbox' in math mode. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
There's no line here to end. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing $ inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing } inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing } inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing \endgroup inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing } inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing $ inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Undefined control sequence. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
LaTeX hooks Error: Illegal mode change in hook 'para/begin'. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Extra }, or forgotten $. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Missing $ inserted. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
\begin{adjustwidth} on input line 2 ended by \end{list}. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
\begin{fullwidth} on input line 2 ended by \end{adjustwidth}. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
\begin{document} ended by \end{fullwidth}. ...centercr second line of title}{3}{section*.3}
Extra \endgroup. \tableofcontents
No file exampleTOC.bbl.
Overfull \hbox (0.4013pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Comment: It is working for me with TeX Live 2023 on macOS. `$ lualatex test_toc.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)`. I have not tested it with version 1.17.0 like you. It looks like I do not have the latest one. Maybe I should update.

Comment: I have updated the installation. It is ok with `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)`.

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the previous `.toc` file if you had one before compiling. That could be a source of error if you upgraded something.